# Not able to view site in browser with railsinstaller due to missing Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am super, super new at programming and I have been trying to get everything set-up on my computer. I have installed RailsInstaller, go to >railsinstaller_demo, and type in rails s. I get the following error though  could not find gem  'uglifier <>= 1.0.3> x86-mingw32'

I looked through the forum and found how to do a gem list and i noticed it was not there. I then went to gembundler and ran $ gem install bundler. I tried again but it did not work.

I am sure the answer is on this site, but i am so new that i see all these lines of code I actually have no idea where to type it in.. I am running Windows 7.

thanks for taking the time to help out a real beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you gone to the `$ railsinstaller_demo` directory and run the `bundle install` command? This will install the gem dependencies for the application; you will not be able to run the server until you've bundled the gems. Additionally, if you're still having issues with the `uglifier` gem, go ahead and remove the line in the Gemfile and then run `bundle install`

If you need further help with the Command Prompt, you an find out more at http://bit.ly/ZajVeW.

Thanks,
Evan